# A boy who finds out his dad implanted military technology in his head

Tags: story-identification, military-sf

I read a newish book some time in 2012-2014, in Barnes & Noble's Teen fiction section, in which this guy of maybe around 16 has a dad who works in a lab doing some research or something. His dad gets into some kind of trouble and tells his son to leave. This kid finds out his dad implanted a vital military technology in his head to I think save him which he can access to make himself more aggressive, stronger, faster. This technology has 5 stages with a hidden 6th stage at the end.

Answer (score 9):

*Amped* by Daniel H. Wilson, published in 2012. A brain implant to control seizures, helps Owen to lead a normal life. He later finds out his father implanted him with an experimental, military prototype that will give him enhanced abilities. Meanwhile, the government fearing those people with implants will surpass normal people, pass regulations making those with implants second class citizens. They are put into camps, attacked. Owen sets out to find what his special abilities are.

[image: Cover of "Amped" by Daniel H. Wilson. The cover shows gray wooden boards with a large eye poking out, but with a computer power button instead of an eyeball.]